# Passing arguments to a program using another program

Tags: c++, createprocess

I have created two executables that accept command line arguments. Now, I want to pass arguments to available executables using C++ (executing on Windows). What is the best way of doing it?

I have used  `CreateProcess()`; it's working fine for static input but I want to input dynamically through CLI.

Comment: Can't you just use the `lpCommandLine` parameter of `CreateProcess()`?

Answer (score 0):

The command-line (with arguments) is one of the parameters to CreateProcess(). Just put whatever arguments you want to pass on to the child executable in there.

What problems are you having with non-static input?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `system(const char*)` and it works for me :)

You pass over a string which contains the command as you type it in the command line. In your case it means the path to the exe file and the arguments it takes, with just spaces in between. It runs the specified process as if it was run from command-line.

For more information: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you already understand that string arguments can be sent via `CreateProcess` at launch time. If you want to continue to send data at run time, you have a couple options.

1. Use console redirection. Since you are already using the Win32 API, it is not too far of a stretch to write to cin of the child process after you have launched it. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I think this might be what you mean by "*input dynamically through CLI*"
2. Use some sort of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). There are Win32 ways of doing this such as [message queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and more platform independent methods such as [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/), or [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/interprocess.html).

There is really more than one way to skin a cat when it comes to IPC and your goal is to do your research and make sure you have made the correct design decisions early on for how your processes will communicate.

If you do decide to use a more full-blown IPC rather than something like console redirection to solve a smaller problem, some questions you should ask yourself are:

- Will I be able to send all the types of data using this type of IPC?
- Will this communication ever need to cross network boundaries?

And, the two big questions that always show up are:

- How maintainable will this be in the future?
- Will this code ever have to run on another platform?

Hopefully this response is not overkill for your question.